# Zuul proxy is not working with utf-8 urls

Tags: utf-8, proxy, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a spring cloud app with Zuul proxy. My zuul proxy doesn't work with UTF-8 urls. How should I configure it?

This will work in my microservice, without proxy.

`http://localhost:8080/rest/item/гандан_тикет`

However when its behind a proxy

`http://localhost:9000/core/rest/item/гандан_тикет`

the `гандан_тикет` will come as `??????_?????` into the microservice.

Comment: create in issue here please: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues

Comment: done https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/647